# Ignore a request in Django

Tags: django, request

What is the most efficient method to have Django selectively/conditionally ignore a request (don't return anything) and drop the connection (don't block future requests)?

Comment: maybe something like [django-simple-blacklist](https://github.com/mnach/django-simple-blacklist)

Comment: @danyamachine No 403

Comment: it seems that you can set a "[PERMISSION_DENIED_CALLBACK](https://github.com/mnach/django-simple-blacklist/blob/master/blacklist/models.py)" when you are configuring your app (`settings.py`).  so, instead of `raise PermissionDenied` (as is done in `permission_denied_default` [here](https://github.com/mnach/django-simple-blacklist/blob/master/blacklist/utils.py)) you could simply not raise an exception.

Comment: Are you saying you want to drop the connection and have the client not receive any response at all?

Comment: @knbk Yes, no response from Django. If they get a response from CloudFlare or something, that's outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally not possible for a WSGI application to drop a request without sending a response. Not returning anything is an error, and the WSGI server will respond with an appropriate error message indicating the application is not working as expected. Even if your WSGI server does not return a response, your web server will simply handle it as a timeout and send a 504 Gateway Timeout.

If you're using nginx as your public-facing webserver, you can send a response from Django with a status code of 444, i.e. `return HttpResponse(status=444)`. If nginx receives this status code from an upstream server, it will drop the request without a response. As far as I know, nginx is the only webserver to provide this option.

If you can't use nginx, I'm afraid there's no option at a webserver level.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, I'm already using nginx so 444 would be perfect. Thanks.